# Check existence of a list in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have a 2d array of numbers. There are 3 values in each row (not necessarily unique), for example:

```
[ [3, 4, 1],
  [8, 1, 3],
  [5, 6, 5] ]
```

There is a process which generates a list of 3 numbers. I check whether this list already exists in my array (same numbers and same sequence), if does, ignore it and if doesn't i add it to the array. This process runs multiple times.

The way I am checking existence is through a loop:

```
c = 0
for s in range(len(l)):
    if np.array_equal(l[s], new):
        c = 1
        break
if c == 0:
    l = np.append(l, new).reshape(-1, 3)
```

where l is my list and new is the list generated by the process.

My question is, is there a way to check without using loop. If the list becomes too big, like 100k+ rows, the checking process takes too much time. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized check across all rows in one-shot, like so -

```
if ~(np.all(l == new,1)).any():
    l = np.append(l, new).reshape(-1, 3)
```

Sample run -

```
In [288]: l
Out[288]: 
array([[4, 4, 0],
       [1, 4, 1],
       [0, 4, 4],
       [4, 0, 4],
       [2, 4, 2]])

In [289]: new
Out[289]: [7, 0, 4]

In [290]: if ~(np.all(l == new,1)).any():
     ...:     l = np.append(l, new).reshape(-1, 3)
     ...:     

In [291]: l
Out[291]: 
array([[4, 4, 0],
       [1, 4, 1],
       [0, 4, 4],
       [4, 0, 4],
       [2, 4, 2],
       [7, 0, 4]])
```

Comment: thanks. seems like exactly what i am looking for. let me read up on the concept of broadcasting as well as the the syntax of your condition (very unfamiliar to me). it would be interesting to evaluate the performance compared with traditional loop that i was using.

Comment: @AbdulQadir That would depend a lot on how far down the rows there is a match if there is one at all.

Comment: it worked well and there is a significant performance gain as well. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if a list in a numpy array this way:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([ [3, 4, 1],
  [8, 1, 3],
  [5, 6, 5] ] )

In [3]: [3,4,1] in a
Out[3]: True
```

Comment: I think `A` in `B` looks for ANY match, instead of ALL matches, as per the question's requirements. So `[0,100,100] in np.arange(12).reshape(-1,3)` gives `True` as well.